# Is there a way to preload multiple .env files with dotenv?

Tags: dotenv

I have an .env file that gets pre-loaded via the dotenv pre-load option.

`node -r dotenv/config bin/server --hot --local`

Is there a way to also *pre-load* a `.env.local` or `.env.*`?

I know it can be achieved in code, but there is a codebase I am working in where I can only reasonably use dotenv preload, doing anything else would require significant modification of the current init source code already in place.

Looking for a solution that would preferably work on Windows 10, but ideally on both Win and OSX

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you load environment variables from .env and .env.local with dotenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731242/how-do-you-load-environment-variables-from-env-and-env-local-with-dotenv)