# How do you load environment variables from .env and .env.local with dotenv?

Tags: node.js, npm, dotenv

This might look like a newbie question, but I am unable to find the way to load environment variables from both .env and .env.local files in node with dotenv.

Is it even possible? How do people load environment variables from both files nowadays if not with dotenv?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quoting from dotenv's npm page

> Should I have multiple .env files?
>
> No. We strongly recommend against having a "main" .env file and an
> "environment" .env file like .env.test. Your config should vary
> between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between
> environments.'

But to use .env.local or .env.test or any other environment.. one at a time is

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` })
```

If you still want to do it refer to dotenv-flow at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow

dotenv-flow comes with the feature of overwriting variables at environments.

---

Edit - 2024 March

My above answer might be obsolete now since the package dotenv supports multiple env files for multiple envs via dotenvx - another package from the same creator that claims to be a better dotenv than dotenv.

https://github.com/dotenvx/dotenvx

Comment: Just a small doubt. If we are using the process.env object to refer to the node env, are we setting the node env at the point where the script/app is being invoked at OS level? I have always used the .env file to set the NODE_ENV value as I have apprehensions that the OS level env variable might cause issues when multiple apps are used on the same instance

Comment: Nope it loads variables from a .env file into the Node app on startup

Comment: Thanks. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow looks helpful.

Comment: It's frustrating that this is at odds with the way create-next-app and next.js in general are set up to function by default which is to only look at a .env.local file. Feels like every time someone tries to confidently set down a rule in tech someone is already breaking it

Comment: Saying "No" to multiple .env files in their docs does not mean they are correct. There are compelling reasons to use .env.[whatever-environment] and many (most?) side with that as the best practice

Comment: True even the npm page has been updated i blv

Answer (score 18):

If `.env.local` file present `dotenv` will override `.env`

```
dotenv.config();
dotenv.config({ path: `.env.local`, override: true });
```

Comment: This will also override any system environment variables you have, unlike the [Abdall Roda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671775/5362302).

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 4):

```
dotenv.config({ path: '.env.local' });
dotenv.config();
```

Comment: And that does what, exactly? How is that different than @mat.twg's answer?

Comment: I answered the question before mat.twg, however as pointed out by Denis Dorohov this does not ovverride any system enviornment variables.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use multiple .env files without any hacks:

```
require('dotenv').config({ 
    path: ['.env.local', '.env'] 
})
```

Your env vars will be set in left to right precedence (`.env.local` vars win in the example above).

**Note**:

Multiple .env files is **not** a bad practice - there are numerous valid use cases for this and this is not the cause of leaked secrets.

The bad practice previously mentioned in the docs has since been rephrased due to confusion (and perhaps incorrect opinion):

> We **strongly** recommend against committing your .env file to version control.

The reasoning is sound - secrets can too easily leak into the repo through carelessness. If you decide to commit any `.env` files, be very careful that secrets never come into the committed files.